# Unable to save data in powershell using Export-Csv

Tags: powershell

Unable to save System.Object contains AD user profile data in below format into csv file using Export-Csv

$output system.object contains below data.

```
EmployeeID        : ********
EmailAddress      : ********
FirstName         : ********
LastName          : ********
UserPrincipalName : ********
```

Command I am running is

```
$outputFile = "C:\Users\vbhardw9\AD_Lookup_Powershell\Output.csv"
$output | Export-Csv -Path $outputFile -Append -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Getting below error

```
Export-Csv : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is 
not valid. Change the value of the "name" argument and run the operation again.
At C:\Users\vbhardw9\AD_Lookup_Powershell\sampleps.ps1:60 char:31
+ ...   $output | Export-Csv -Path $outputFile -Append -NoTypeInformation - ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Export-Csv], PSArgumentExc 
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsv 
   Command
```

Comment: What is the value of `$output` ?

Comment: I would not use the variable $output in PS.  Try a different variable.  The error is says in the object $output contains a property "name", but what you are posting doesn't contain "name".  There is a discontinuity in what you posted and what the error is indicating.

Comment: Looks like your `$output` array is the result of another part of the script that lets it store the output in `Format-List` format. That means it does not contain data, but **strings** instead.. `Export-Csv` expects real data in the form of **objects**

Comment: @jdweng, unlike `$input`, `$output` is a perfectly valid custom variable name - picking a different name cannot be expected to make a difference. The error message refers to a _method / constructor argument_ with name `name`, which suggests that an internal error is accidentally surfaced, which smells like a bug.

Comment: We will only know if this is a bug, or not, when we know how `$output` got it's value when it was used as input for `Export-CSV ...` like in this question was done.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the error is related to the use of `-Append`. You can confirm or rule that out by doing a test run _without_ `-Append`. To get to the bottom of this, please [edit] your question to include the first 2 lines of the target CSV (anonymize, if needed), as well as the result from `@($object)[0].psobject.Properties.Name`